# Create instance of dynamically created generic collection

Tags: c#, reflection

how can I cast object to generic collection, when I don't know of result type?

```
ICollection<IEntity> entityCollection = modelPropertyInfo.GetValue(result) as ICollection<IEntity>;
if (entityCollection == null)
{
   var targetType = prop.Attribute("target").Value;
   string entityTypeString = "MyNamespace." + targetType + ", MyAssambly";
   Type entityType = GetTypeFromCache(entityTypeString); // here I get right type or null
   if (entityType != null)
   {
       object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Collection<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { entityType })); // how I have instance of genereic collection
       // how to do something like this:
       // entityCollection = o as ICollection<entityType> dynamically ???
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the collection to be in terms of abstraction: which interface or base class do you think it will always be?

Comment: It's class implementing IEntity interface, but when I try something like this:

Comment: I don't think that a `Collection<DerivedEnity>` can be cast at all into a `ICollection<IEntity>` since `ICollection<T>` is not covariant.

Comment: It's class implementing IEntity interface, yes I can create instance of Collection<IEntity>, but then is problem in settings up property of agregated entity, for example entity had property of type ICollection<Dog> and I create collection of IEntity and I add same items (dogs) into this collection (Dog implements IEntity) but CL runtime throws exception when I try set property of ICollection<IEntity> into property of type Collection<Dog>...